# ayuda con error en login laravel

Tags: php, laravel

cuando ingreso el nombre y la contraseña en mi formulario me manda a error los datos llegan al controlador

```
    [2019-08-23 19:56:23] local.ERROR: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\app\resources\views\home.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\\laragon\\www\\app\
esources\\views\\home.blade.php) at C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\storage\\framework\\views\\5d39dcde79b6663de48c51ce0b0753b721df2fc3.php:49, ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to get property of non-object at C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\storage\\framework\\views\\5d39dcde79b6663de48c51ce0b0753b721df2fc3.php:49)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine.php(45): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 1)
#1 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\...', Array)
#2 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\View.php(142): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get('C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\...', Array)
#3 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\View.php(125): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#4 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\View.php(90): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#5 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Response.php(42): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#6 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\symfony\\http-foundation\\Response.php(202): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#7 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(748): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#8 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(720): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#9 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(680): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#10 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php(24): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): App\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\LocaleMiddleware.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): App\\Http\\Middleware\\LocaleMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(75): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(682): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#37 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(657): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(623): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#39 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(612): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#50 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#53 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#54 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#56 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#57 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#58 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#59 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#60 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 C:\\laragon\\www\\app\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\...')
#62 {main}
```

use AuthenticatesUsers;

public function login(Request $request){

```
$credentials = $request->only('usuario', 'password');

// if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
if (Auth::attempt(['usuario' => request('usuario'), 'password' => request('password'), 'habilitado' => 1])) {
    // return 'ok';
    return view('home');
}else{
    return 'error';
}
```

}

**no me manda ningun error laravel solamente me manda al else error**

```
archivo env
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=produccion
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

mysql usuario root contraseña secret tabla produccion
```

es una practica así que puedo compartir los datos

Comment: Que es 'usuario'? Un campo de la tabla de usuarios como 'email' ? Al parecer usas un sistema de autenticación que has creado tú y no el que crea Laravel con make:auth. Deberías compartir como lo has hecho para que alguien pueda ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar request como una variable tipo Objeto apuntando a sus atributos con **->**

```
$credentials = $request->only('usuario', 'password');

if (Auth::attempt(['usuario' => $request->usuario, 'password' => $request->password, 'habilitado' => 1])) {
     // return 'ok';
     return view('home');
 }else{
     return 'error';
 }
```

En caso de querer usar la variable **credentials**, tienes que manejarla como un Array, te quedaría algo así

```
$credentials = $request->only('usuario', 'password');

if (Auth::attempt(['usuario' => $credentials['usuario'], 'password' => $credentials['password'], 'habilitado' => 1])) {
     // return 'ok';
     return view('home');
 }else{
     return 'error';
 }
```

Tambien te recomiendo si no tienes clave en tu BDD dejar el blanco el campo en el .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=produccion
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Para verificar mas a fondo el error prueba uno de estos métodos

1.- Poner solo el codigo de inico para forzar el bloque de codigo

```
$credentials = $request->only('usuario', 'password');
Auth::attempt(['usuario' => $credentials['usuario'], 'password' => $credentials['password'], 'habilitado' => 1]);

return view('home');
```

2.- Intentar con try catch

```
$credentials = $request->only('usuario', 'password');
try {
    Auth::attempt(['usuario' => $credentials['usuario'], 'password' => $credentials['password'], 'habilitado' => 1]); 
     return view('home');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    \Log::info($e);
     dd($e);
}
```

En este caso te mostrara el error en el archivo ubicado en Storage > Logs > archivo_con_la_fecha_actual.log y tambien te dara un pantallazo con el error.

Comment: Te recomiendo tambien usar los Log de laravel, sirven para mostar en un archivo tus variables, son simples agregas a tu codigo por ejemplo \Log::info($credentials); y prodras verlo en la carpeta Storage > Logs > (el que tenga la fecha actual) estos puedes borrarlos cuando quieras y no pasara nada, puedes borrar tanto su contenido como el archivo como tal

Comment: me sigue lmandando a error  ¿que archivos necesitas para ver mas detallado el problema?

Comment: cual es el error?

Comment: no me manda erro me rediregi return 'error';

Comment: vuelve a leer mi respuesta, la modifique para que puedas generar el error

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\app\resources\views\home.blade.php)